# Javascript calculator. How to stop multiple operands?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a calculator as a learning project for myself. It is working fine except I cannot figure out how to stop people from adding app breaking inputs such as 1++-*/4. I have tried various things like splitting my current display into an array and comparing it to another array with all the operators. I have also tried if(output.includes(input){ blah blah }.

I tried adding an extra else if to the `getbuttonpress` which went something like this else if(input == "*" || input == "+" || input == "/" || input = "-"){do something}
It didn't really work out for me.

Could someone please explain some different methods that I could use to resolve the issue?

Here is my code:

```js
var resultDisplayed = false;

function getButtonPress() {
  var input = this.value;

  if (input == "=") {
    console.log("bang");
    getResult();
  } else if (resultDisplayed && input < 10) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input;
    resultDisplayed = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += input;
    console.log(input);
    resultDisplayed = false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("button")).forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', getButtonPress);
  });
};

function getResult() {
  var result = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
  var resultCalculated = eval(result);
  console.log(resultCalculated);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = resultCalculated;
  resultDisplayed = true;
}
```

```css
/* Fonts from Google Fonts - more at https://fonts.google.com */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700');
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#calculator {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  width: 19%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttonContainer {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#screen {
  width: 90%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="screen">
      <h1 id="output">0</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
      <button class="button" value="7">
          <h1 class = "number">7</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="8">
          <h1 class = "number">8</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="9">
          <h1 class = "number">9</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="+">
          <h1 class = "number">+</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="4">
          <h1 class = "number">4</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="5">
          <h1 class = "number">5</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="6">
          <h1 class = "number">6</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="-">
          <h1 class = "operator">-</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="1">
          <h1 class = "number">1</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="2">
          <h1 class = "number">2</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="3">
          <h1 class = "number">3</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="*">
          <h1 class = "operator">*</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value=".">
          <h1 class = "operator">.</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="0">
          <h1 class = "number">0</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="=">
          <h1 class = "operator">=</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="/">
          <h1 class = "operator">/</h1>
        </button>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `getButtonPress` seems like a good moment to check if the last character was an operand.

Comment: You could check the last character in the 'output' element (within `getButtonPress`), and if it matches one of the operands, then you replace it, instead of adding on.

Comment: Whenever you click any operand button you need to take the last val from the input and see if its one of the operands, if it is skip like below.     $('#button-plus').click(function() {
var lastChar = $('#disp').val().slice(-1);
var firstChar = $('#disp').val().slice(0);
if (lastChar == '*' || lastChar == '-' || lastChar == '+' || lastChar == '/' || lastChar == '.' || lastChar == '(' || lastChar == '%'){
    // DO NOTHING
    }
else if (firstChar == '0'){
    // DO NOTHING
    }
else {
  addChar(this.form.display, '+');
  }
  $('#disp').removeClass("result");
  dotCount = 0;
});

Comment: The above solution has been taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027346/prevent-multiple-decimals-points-in-calculation-field

Comment: @user8271644 that is really hard to read :P

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `try catch` statement.

It may not be the best solution. You should build some kind of parser, but this will also work very well.

```js
var resultDisplayed = false;
//1++-*/4
function getButtonPress() {
  var input = this.value;

  if (input == "=") {
    //console.log("bang");
    getResult();
  } else if (resultDisplayed && input < 10) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input;
    resultDisplayed = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += input;
    //console.log(input);
    resultDisplayed = false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("button")).forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', getButtonPress);
  });
};

function getResult() {
  try{
  var result = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
  var resultCalculated = eval(result);
  console.log(resultCalculated);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = resultCalculated;
  resultDisplayed = true;
  }catch(e){
   console.log("Invalid expression");
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
/* Fonts from Google Fonts - more at https://fonts.google.com */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700');
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#calculator {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  width: 19%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttonContainer {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#screen {
  width: 90%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="screen">
      <h1 id="output">0</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
      <button class="button" value="7">
          <h1 class = "number">7</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="8">
          <h1 class = "number">8</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="9">
          <h1 class = "number">9</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="+">
          <h1 class = "number">+</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="4">
          <h1 class = "number">4</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="5">
          <h1 class = "number">5</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="6">
          <h1 class = "number">6</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="-">
          <h1 class = "operator">-</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="1">
          <h1 class = "number">1</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="2">
          <h1 class = "number">2</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="3">
          <h1 class = "number">3</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="*">
          <h1 class = "operator">*</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value=".">
          <h1 class = "operator">.</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="0">
          <h1 class = "number">0</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="=">
          <h1 class = "operator">=</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="/">
          <h1 class = "operator">/</h1>
        </button>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP want to prevent the insertion

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the problem though. It still allows the invalid user behavior to continue (1++-*/4). Instead I think it would be better to prevent that behavior by replacing symbols instead of allowing them to stack.

Comment: Although I have noticed that 2**2 seems to be a valid equation which would not be possible if the symbol gets replaced.

Comment: Yes I feel this is the best solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just realised also if you want to use minus numbers like 8+-7 your code works for that too.

Comment: Yea it'll work for all valid javascript expressions. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code to your getButtonPress function

It will check whether both the current input and previous entry are operators.

If yes, it will replace the previous operator with new one

```
var element=document.getElementById("output");
  if (/[+-\/*]/.test(this.value) && /[+-\/*]$/.test(element.innerHTML)) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(element.innerHTML[element.innerHTML.length - 1], '');
  }
```

```js
var resultDisplayed = false;

function getButtonPress() {
  var input;
  var element=document.getElementById("output");
  if (/[+-\/*]/.test(this.value) && /[+-\/*]$/.test(element.innerHTML)) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(element.innerHTML[element.innerHTML.length - 1], '');
  }
  input = this.value;
  if (input == "=") {
    console.log("bang");
    getResult();
  } else if (resultDisplayed && input < 10) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input;
    resultDisplayed = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += input;
    resultDisplayed = false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("button")).forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', getButtonPress);
  });
};

function getResult() {
  var result = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
  var resultCalculated = eval(result);
  console.log(resultCalculated);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = resultCalculated;
  resultDisplayed = true;
}
```

```css
/* Fonts from Google Fonts - more at https://fonts.google.com */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700');
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#calculator {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  width: 19%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttonContainer {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#screen {
  width: 90%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="screen">
      <h1 id="output">0</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
      <button class="button" value="7">
          <h1 class = "number">7</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="8">
          <h1 class = "number">8</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="9">
          <h1 class = "number">9</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="+">
          <h1 class = "number">+</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="4">
          <h1 class = "number">4</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="5">
          <h1 class = "number">5</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="6">
          <h1 class = "number">6</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="-">
          <h1 class = "operator">-</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="1">
          <h1 class = "number">1</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="2">
          <h1 class = "number">2</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="3">
          <h1 class = "number">3</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="*">
          <h1 class = "operator">*</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value=".">
          <h1 class = "operator">.</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="0">
          <h1 class = "number">0</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="=">
          <h1 class = "operator">=</h1>
        </button>
      <button class="button" value="/">
          <h1 class = "operator">/</h1>
        </button>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The final `else` in `getButtonPress` has to look like this:

```
else {
  var operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "."],
    lastCharacter = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML[document.getElementById("output").innerHTML.length - 1];

  if(!operators.includes(lastCharacter) || !operators.includes(input)){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += input;
    console.log(input);
    resultDisplayed = false;
  }
}
```

Intuitively,

```
!operators.includes(lastCharacter) || !operators.includes(input)
```

can be thought of as the logical expression

```
operators.includes(lastCharacter) → ¬operators.includes(input)
```

which means *“if the last character is an operator, the next input isn’t an operator”*. if this is the case, the symbol is added to the output screen, otherwise it isn’t.

This still won’t prevent you from entering numbers like `2.5.6` or ending the expression with an operator, but this solves the described problem.

Answer (score 0):

another option, delete `0` in start and delete operands in last character when `getResult()` called

```js
var resultDisplayed = false;

function getButtonPress() {
  var input = this.value,
    output = document.getElementById("output");

  if(input == "=") {
    //console.log("bang");
    getResult();
  }
  else if(resultDisplayed && input < 10) {
    output.innerHTML = input;
    resultDisplayed = false;
  }
  else {
    //console.log(input);
    var currentValue = output.innerHTML;
    // start with 0 + digit, delete it 
    if((currentValue+input).match(/^0\d/)){
     input = input;
    }
    // end with +-*/ delete it
    else if(currentValue.match(/[-\+\*\/]$/) && input.match(/[-\+\*\/]/)) {
      input = currentValue.slice(0, -1) +''+ input;
    }
    else{
     input = currentValue + input 
    }
    output.innerHTML = input;
    resultDisplayed = false;
  }
}

[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("button")).forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', getButtonPress);
});


function getResult() {
  var result = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
  if(result.match(/[-\+\*\/]$/))
    result = result.slice(0, -1);
  var resultCalculated = eval(result);
  console.log(resultCalculated);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = resultCalculated;
  resultDisplayed = true;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700');
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#calculator {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  width: 19%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttonContainer {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#screen {
  width: 90%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="screen">
    <h1 id="output">0</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button class="button" value="7">
      <h1 class="number">7</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="8">
      <h1 class="number">8</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="9">
      <h1 class="number">9</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="+">
      <h1 class="number">+</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="4">
      <h1 class="number">4</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="5">
      <h1 class="number">5</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="6">
      <h1 class="number">6</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="-">
      <h1 class="operator">-</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="1">
      <h1 class="number">1</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="2">
      <h1 class="number">2</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="3">
      <h1 class="number">3</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="*">
      <h1 class="operator">*</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value=".">
      <h1 class="operator">.</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="0">
      <h1 class="number">0</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="=">
      <h1 class="operator">=</h1>
    </button>
    <button class="button" value="/">
      <h1 class="operator">/</h1>
    </button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code that will not accept multiple operands

```
   function calc(opr)
  {
    var a2=0;


    var a1 = cal.display.value;
    a2 = a1.charAt(a1.length-1);
    if(a2 == '/' || a2 == '+' || a2 == '-' || a2 == '*')
    { 
      cal.display.value = a1.substring(0,a1.length-1);
      cal.display.value += opr;       
    }
    else
    {
     cal.display.value+= opr;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you click any operand button you need to take the last val from the input and see if its one of the operands, if it is skip like below.

```
    $('#button-plus').click(function() {
var lastChar = $('#disp').val().slice(-1);
var firstChar = $('#disp').val().slice(0);
if (lastChar == '*' || lastChar == '-' || lastChar == '+' || lastChar == '/' || lastChar == '.' || lastChar == '(' || lastChar == '%'){
    // DO NOTHING
    }
else if (firstChar == '0'){
    // DO NOTHING
    }
else {
  addChar(this.form.display, '+');
  }
  $('#disp').removeClass("result");
  dotCount = 0;
});
```

Comment: Is this JQuery?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Ah I am trying not to use JQuery and instead do everything with plain JS while I am learning.